# Asymptotic approximation of Fisher information matrix for small Gaussian perturbation

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, it.information-theory

Let
$$
X=Y/a+b+\epsilon Z,
$$
where $Y\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $Z\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ are independent.  Also define $\theta=(\lambda,a,b,\epsilon)$. The Fisher information matrix
$$
I_X(\theta)=-\mathsf E(\nabla_\theta^2\log f_X(X|\theta))
$$
is very complicated; however, the joint information
$$
I_{X,Y}(\theta)=-\mathsf E(\nabla_\theta^2\log f_{X,Y}(X,Y|\theta))
$$
is very simple.  Comparing numerical calculations of the incomplete-data information $I_X$ to the explicit expression for the complete-data information $I_{X,Y}$ shows that $I_{X,Y}$ provides an excellent approximation to $I_X$ as $\epsilon$ becomes small.

Can it be shown that
$$
I_X(\theta)\sim I_{X,Y}(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\lambda } & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{\lambda ^2+\lambda }{a^4 \epsilon ^2} &
   -\frac{\lambda }{a^2 \epsilon ^2} & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{\lambda }{a^2 \epsilon ^2} & \frac{1}{\epsilon ^2}
   & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{\epsilon ^2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
as $\epsilon\to 0^+$?

We have by the properties of logarithms the *chain rule* for information
$$
I_X(\theta)=I_{X,Y}(\theta)-I_{Y|X}(\theta),
$$
so this would amount to showing $I_{Y|X}$ is negligible in comparison to $I_{X,Y}$ for small $\epsilon$.

---

*Additional Information:*

The density for $X$ can be expressed by integrating the joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ over the (discrete) variable $Y$ yielding
$$
f_X(x|\theta)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\underbrace{\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}\phi(x;b+k/a,\epsilon^2)}_{f_{X,Y}(x,k|\theta)}.
$$
Here, $\phi$ is the Gaussian probability density parameterized in terms of mean and variance.

The characteristic function of $X$ is also quite simple and inverting the characteristic function yields (after a few applications of Euler's identity)
$$
f_X(x|\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\exp(\lambda(\cos(t/a)-1)-\epsilon^2t^2/2)\cos((b-x)t+\lambda\sin(t/a))\,\mathrm dt.
$$
As we can see, no simplification occurs when considering the log of the density function for $X$. When evaluating $[I_X(\theta)]_{i,j}-\mathsf E(\partial_{\theta_i}\partial_{\theta_j}\log f_X(X|\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4))$, when inevitably end up with an integral containing a term with $f_X$ in the denominator, which is intractable.

Comment: Can you also write the FIM for the X variable also i.e. $I_{X}(\theta)$? The density is the convolution of the density of Y and Z (with mean b); just to see at least where the $\epsilon$ shows up.

Comment: @ThomasKojar The FIM for $X$ becomes a gigantic mess.  I did include a couple different forms of $f_X$, which reveals the problem.  The integrand for the integral form of $f_X$ is an even function in $t$ so it is also possible to express the integral over $(-\infty,\infty)$.